# Import a colormap defined in a different file

Tags: python, imshow

I have a defined a colormap which I use with imshow for several small scripts...

The colormap is in its own colormap.py file which looks like this:

```
import matplotlib

#define colorcode for matrix
cdict = {'red': ((0,1,1),
                 (0.2,0,0),
                 (0.5,0.275,0.275),
                 (0.7,1,1),
                 (1,1,1)
                 ),
         'green': ((0,1,1),
                   (0.2,0.275,0.275),
                   (0.5,1,1),
                   (0.7,1,1),
                   (1,0,0)
                   ),
         'blue': ((0,1,1),
                  (0.2,1,1),
                  (0.5,0,0),
                  (0.7,0,0),
                  (1,0,0)
                  )}
FFT_colormap = matplotlib.colors.LinearSegmentedColormap('my_colormap',cdict,256)
```

Now I have a different file with a script where I want to plot a matrix. What I want is a code which works like this:

```
from colormap.py import FFT_colormap
import pylab as pl

pl.imshow(data, cmap=FFT_colormap)
```

Well... since FFT_colormap is no function I can't import it like this. So is there a way to import such a colormap?

Answer (score -1):

I found the solution....

with `execfile('colorcodes.py')` the colorcode is loaded into my new script...